# The Caesar cipher works only for uppercase letters (CS50)

Tags: c, encryption, cs50

My program works only for uppercase letters and I can't figure the problem out. Everything seems to be fine, but it actually isn't. This is a task from CS50 course (week2), by the way.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{ /* Main should take only one parameter (except program execution, of course) */
  if (argc != 2)
    return 1;

  string text = GetString(); // text to encrypt

  int i, l = strlen(text);
  int k = atoi(argv[1]); // shift value (key)
  /* Shift value should be less or equal to 26 */
  if (k > 26)
    k = k % 26;

  for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
  { /* Making sure the character to encrypt is a letter (from English alphabet) */
    if ((islower(text[i])) || (isupper(text[i])))
    {
      if ((islower(text[i])) && ((text[i] + k) > 'z'))
        text[i] = ('a' + text[i] + k - 'z' - 1);
      if ((isupper(text[i])) && ((text[i] + k) > 'Z'))
        text[i] = ('A' + text[i] + k - 'Z' - 1);
      else
        text[i] = text[i] + k;
    }
    printf("%c", text[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Result

```
caesar.exe 13
HELLO WORLD hello world
URYYB JBEYQ uryyk sknyq
```

Comment: you can use `toUpper` function at first

Comment: And then convert the encrypted character to lower case? Of course it'll work, but I want to find out why my program doesn't work =)

Comment: The logic in your `if` statements is a little weird.  What letters are going to be greater than `z`?  You might consider using more variables to simplify your code.  You shouldn't need to call `toupper` or `tolower` more than once per character.

Comment: For example: 'z' = 122; 'z' + k (k = 13). Then char = 135.

Comment: Aside: `if ((islower(text[i])) || (isupper(text[i])))` would be easier as `if (isalpha(text[i]))`

Comment: Your treatment of upper and lower case looks similar, but is not the same, because the uppercase has the instruction `else text[i] = text[i] + k;`. But in lowercase that will always be executed.

Comment: `if ((isupper(text[i]))...` --> `else if ((isupper(text[i]))...`

Comment: LOL the missing "else" solved it. Thanks =) I thought it works with "if" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This whole block;

```
if ((islower(text[i])) || (isupper(text[i])))
{
  if ((islower(text[i])) && ((text[i] + k) > 'z'))
    text[i] = ('a' + text[i] + k - 'z' - 1);
  if ((isupper(text[i])) && ((text[i] + k) > 'Z'))
    text[i] = ('A' + text[i] + k - 'Z' - 1);
  else
    text[i] = text[i] + k;
}
```

Can be reduced to:

```
if (islower(text[i]) || isupper(text[i]))
{
    int base = islower(text[i]) ? 'a' : 'A';
    int ord = text[i] - base;  // normalize text[i] to be between [0-25]
    ord = (ord + k) % 26;      // rotate
    text[i] = base + ord;      // convert back to alphabet value
}
```

Comment: One quick note: There might be a bug here if `k` is negative and `(ord + k) < 0`.  Just normalize k to a positive number before you enter the loop.